# Lowest Maximum Visits in the milestones problem

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Hi I was given a problem where I was given the numbers like 1, 50000, 10000, 3, 10001, 10003 and assume that they are the milestones that a runner crosse.

So that means, first he will run from 1 to 50k and then comes back to 10k, and then to 3, and to 10001 and to 10003 etc. Now I have to find the lowest maximum visited milestone in his entire journey.

here is the program I have written. is there any better version for this, to use less space instead of 50k array.

```
public class LowestMaxVisits {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(50000);
        list.add(10000);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(10001);
        list.add(10003);
        int [] arr = new int[50000];
        long smillis = System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000;
        for(int i=0; i<list.size()-1; i++){
            int start = list.get(i)-1;
            int end = list.get(i+1)-1;
            if(start > end){
                int temp = start;
                start = end;
                end = temp;
            }
            while(start < end){
                arr[start]++;
                arr[end]++;
                start++;
                end--;
            }
        }
        int maxVisits = -1;
        int index = -1;
        for(int k=0;k<arr.length;k++){
            if(arr[k] > maxVisits){
                index = k;
                maxVisits = arr[k];
            }
        }
        long emillis = System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000;
        System.out.println("Time taken---"+ (emillis-smillis));
        System.out.println("Here is the highest---"+(index+1));
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "lowest maximum visited milestone"?

Comment: If you run the program above, you will get the result 10000, since the user will cross that milestone 4 times and also the 10001 but we need to return the lowest one, so thats why its 10000

Comment: You would need to copy the milestone array and sort it. Then use that for counting the visits along with an array of `int` the same size as the milestones array (all starting at 0). Increase the int at the same index of the sorted milestones array when that milestone has been "passed".

Comment: if we sort it, we will lose the order, please look at the given milestone samples I have given in my above solution

Comment: That's why I said you copy it, but I don't think you understand why I would sort it for the algorithm. Also, why wouldn't the answer be 4 since that's the lowest number that was "passed" the most amount of times?

Comment: it is not 4, cuz if you take the above sample, you pass 10000 most times, the runner will start at 1 and to 50000, from 50000 to 10000, from 10000 to 3, 3 to 10001, 10001 to 10003.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205333/discussion-between-ramya-b-and-hewiefreeman).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code based on how I explained to solve the problem in my comment:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class LowestMaxVisits {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> milestones = new ArrayList<Integer>(){{
            add(1);
            add(50000);
            add(10000);
            add(3);
            add(10001);
            add(10003);
        }};

        System.out.println(getHighestMilestone(milestones));
    }

    public static int getHighestMilestone(List<Integer> milestones) {
        // Make a sorted milestones array
        List<Integer> sortedMilestones = new ArrayList<>(milestones);
        int t;
        for (int i = 0; i < sortedMilestones.size() - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = sortedMilestones.size() - 1; j > i; j--) {
                if (sortedMilestones.get(i) > sortedMilestones.get(j)) {
                    t = sortedMilestones.get(i);
                    sortedMilestones.set(i, sortedMilestones.get(j));
                    sortedMilestones.set(j, t);
                }
            }
        }
        // Count the amount of times passed for each milestone
        t = 0;
        int[] mPassed = new int[sortedMilestones.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < milestones.size() - 1; i++) {
            if (i == 0 || (milestones.get(i) > sortedMilestones.get(t))) {
                for (int j = t + 1; j < sortedMilestones.size(); j++) {
                    mPassed[j]++;
                    if (Objects.equals(sortedMilestones.get(j), milestones.get(i))) {
                        t = j;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                for (int j = t - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                    mPassed[j]++;
                    if (Objects.equals(sortedMilestones.get(j), milestones.get(i))) {
                        t = j;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // Get the highest count and set it to t
        t = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < mPassed.length; i++) {
            if (t < mPassed[i]) {
                t = mPassed[i];
            }
        }
        // Get lowest milestone with the higest count
        for (int i = 0; i < mPassed.length; i++) {
            if (mPassed[i] == t) {
                t = sortedMilestones.get(i);
                break;
            }
        }
        return t;
    }

}
```

You need to sort the copied array in order to iterate through them as if they were "places", back and forth according to the order of stops. You also need it for finding the lowest number milestone with the most visits.

Edit: Instead of making a list as big as the largest number in our array (in your case 50,000), this only needs to make a copy of the milestones array and another integer array of the same size. Note: a `int t;` variable is also made and reused for multiple purposes throughout `getHighestMilestone()`.

Answer (score 0):

The key observation here is that only the relative order of the milestones matter, not their absolute positions. If we changed the numbers in your example to `0, 5, 2, 1, 3, 4`, the problem is still the same, as long as we convert the final output back. If `N` is the number of milestones in your input, there are at most `N` distinct positions so we can map them to the integers from `0` to `N - 1`. One way we can do this quickly is to insert all the positions as keys into an ordered map structure, which I believe is called `TreeMap` in Java, and then iterating through the keys in increasing order and assigning the next integer as the value for each key.

Now we can count the number of times each milestone was passed using an array, which only needs to be `N` elements large. When we move from one milestone to the next we can just increment all the array elements in between. However, we might have to increment almost the entire array every time, and we can make this faster. If `f(x)` is the number of times the milestone `x` was passed and `a` is the array, instead of storing `f(x)` in `a[x]` we store `f(0)` in `a[0]` and `f(x) - f(x - 1)` in `a[x]` for `x` greater than 0. Now to increment the range `[l, r]`, we only need to increment the `a[l]` and decrement the `a[r + 1]`.

After we processed all the milestones this way, we can iterate through the array and accumulate the elements to obtain the number of times each milestone is passed. It's not hard to see that `f(x) = a[0] + a[1] + ... + a[x]`.

Here's the pseudocode:

```
let mp be an ordered map structure such as a TreeMap which maps integers to integers and stores elements in order of their key
for each milestone ms:
    if ms isn't in mp:
        insert ms as a key into mp paired with an arbitrary value
let index = 0
for each key-value pair pos in ms in increasing order of key:
    set the value of pos to index
    increment index
for each milestone ms:
    set ms to mp[ms]
let a be an array
define incrementRange(l, r):
    increment a[l]
    decrement a[r + 1]
for each milestone ms:
    let prev be the previous milestone
    if ms is greater than prev:
        incrementRange(prev + 1, ms)
    else:
        incrementRange(ms, prev - 1)
for i from 1 to N - 1:
    add a[i - 1] to a[i]
let maxVisited be the minimum index in a of an element with maximum value
output the key in mp with value maxVisited
```

Time complexity: `O(N log N)` Space: `O(N)`

I don't think it gets faster than this.